# Get current URL, and strip it down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a URL like:

```
http://url.test.com/account/name/pages/Stuff.html
```

I want to take 'Stuff' and apply that as a class to body.

```
<body class="Stuff">

...

</body>
```

1. How can I get the current URL?
2. How can I extract the text 'Stuff' after the final '/'
3. Then add the class 'Stuff' to body?

Comment: This is JavaScript question, not a jQuery question.  I've added the appropriate flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1. url=location.href

2. fname=url.match(/.*\/(.*)\./)[1]

3. document.body.className=fname
```

Comment: Can someone expand on this a little further?

Possibly give me a full example with bits and pieces require?

Answer (score 3):

Not the shortest of code but substring is pretty fast so...

```
var page = window.location.href;
page = page.substring(page.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
page = page.substring(0, page.lastIndexOf('.'));
document.body.className = page;
```

*edited because I forgot to include part 3*

Comment: This is certainly much better than using regex.

Comment: It should be noted that `substring` is being used here and not `substr`.  The difference being that `substring` takes an index as its second parameter as opposed to a length.

Answer (score 0):

See: [stackoverflow.com:how-can-i-add-a-class-to-the-body-tag-using-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018001/how-can-i-add-a-class-to-the-body-tag-using-jquery/2018037#2018037)

I wanted to say that this question is a duplicate but I think your title expresses the problem better.