# jQuery doesn't work on IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, addclass

I have the following jQuery script, which is actually being ignored by Internet Explorer (7 and 8). It works OK in FF and Chrome.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $("body").addClass("newclass");
</script>
```

It's very simple, yet I don't know for what reason IE ignores it. Know that the code is loaded as dynamic content with JAVA (which shouldn't be a problem since the rest of the scripts work). I tried to call tha script as a function in a external file, but nothing happens either. Can anyone help me to understand where is my error? Or help me to understand IE?

Comment: Where in the document is this running? In the head?

Comment: Wouldn't sound too crazy to say, but maybe IE has a bug with dynamically adding classes to the body tag... maybe this would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018001/how-can-i-add-a-class-to-the-body-tag-using-jquery

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or perhaps in the 'ready' event of the document would be better

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').addClass('newclass');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that you would have issues in Firefox and Chrome as well if this was the issue but try

```
$(function () {
    $('body').addClass('newclass');
});
```

just to be sure that it is called after the document is loaded. Maybe IE needs that.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`

This way, JQuery will only run it once the page has full loaded.

If you don't do this, the code will be executed as soon as it can be, which may be before the DOM has loaded, so you may not have a body element to add the class to.

The fact that some browsers work and others don't implies that different browsers (a) load the page at different speeds, and/or (b) perform initial loading tasks in a different order. But you shouldn't need to worry about that. Just call `$.ready()` and it'll all be done in the right order for you by JQuery.